# mysql2 gem not working after updating to Ubuntu 16.04 - libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, mysql2

Everything worked fine prior to the update.
Using ruby 1.9.3p392 with RVM with rails (3.2.12)
Using **MySQL** 5.7.16 and Nginx and Unicorn

Log shows

```
LoadError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/bill/apps/xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

I tried:

1. uninstall/install mysql2 gem
2. Running `bundle install`

Nothing worked. Anyone had that problem after updating ?

Comment: shouldn't `mysql` gem be installed and looked in directory for 1.9.3 version? (`/home/bill/apps/xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/..`)

Comment: Yes thanks. There was a compatibility issue between my older mysql2 gem and the newly installed mysql 5.7. Changing gem version in my gemfile gives me another error

Comment: ok my error is now: LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.).    mysql2 is part of the gemfile and I also installed activerecord-mysql2-adapter. I will check if it's not a socket problem

Comment: It's strange. Are you sure `Gemfile.lock` contains required gem `activerecord-mysql2-adapter` and you have run `bundle` to install this gem?

Comment: Ok.. now it works. I changed my gemfile to a older version (  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.17') which is compatible with my rails and mysql 5.7. Then Bundle install from my computer... pushed it to my server and cap deployed it. The error went away. Many thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Remove and reinstall `mysql2` gem.

I had the same thing. Upgraded from Ubuntu 14 to 16 and saw this same error.

To fix it, I just uninstalled the `mysql2` gem and reinstalled it using bundler.

1. Uninstall `mysql2` gem:

   ```
   $ bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2
   ```
2. Reinstall `mysql2` gem:

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```

The reason is because it has to install native extensions when it installs the gem, and a large system change like upgrading the OS 1 or more versions requires rebuilding those native extensions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a fix somewhere else that suggested `gem uninstall mysql2` which did not work.  Forcing it to remove it from the bundle with the `bundle exec` was the important part for me.

Comment: @mrrogers Yes, that's gotten me a few times. `bundle exec` is like its own environment. Also confusing is when when people do `gem install` and `sudo gem install`. Can lead to mass chaos.